# Best proof for the number of independent components of a totally (anti) symmetric tensor

Tags: combinatorics, tensors

I'm asking this question for future reference. Given a totally antisymmetric and a totally symmetric tensor having $k$ indices living in $n$ dimensions. Denote the antisymmetric and symmetric tensor by $A_{i_1\dots i_k}$ and $S_{i_1\dots i_k}$ respectively. Without these symmetries would have $n^k$ independent components. Because of their (anti) symmetricity each of the components can be written such that the indices appear in ascending order. For example $A_{321}=-A_{123}$. The independent components can be written as a list where the indices of each element are ascending. The antisymmetric tensor has the additional constraint that no two indices can be the same.
\begin{align}
\text{indep}(A)&=\left\{A_{i_1\dots i_k}\middle|1\leq i_1<\dots<i_k\leq n\right\}\\
\text{indep}(S)&=\left\{S_{i_1\dots i_k}\middle|1\leq i_1\leq\dots\leq i_k\leq n\right\}
\end{align}
Now it is known that the number of independent components are given by
\begin{align}
\#(A)\equiv\big|\,\text{indep}(A)\,\big|&=\pmatrix{n\\k}\\
\#(S)\equiv\big|\,\text{indep}(S)\,\big|&=\pmatrix{n+k-1\\k}
\end{align}
My question is what are nice ways to proof this last statement (both for the symmetric/antisymmetric case). With  nice I mean either easy to remember, intuitive or elegant. The antisymmetric case has been proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1097262/339958) and both cases have also been proven in [this paper](http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Eyangob/symmetric%20tensor.pdf). The reason I'm asking this question is to have these facts nicely together and also to get some more proofs to make it easier to remember. Also I found a nice proof myself.

Answer (score 1):

The antisymmetric case can be rephrased as 'I have $n$ digits. In how many ways can I group them in groups of $k$'. This has the answer $\pmatrix {n\\k}$.

---

The symmetric case is also in the form of an binomial coefficient so this invites us to the idea of writing the components of a symmetric $n,k$ tensor as an antisymmetric $n+k-1,k$ tensor. Let's call it $A'$. The difference between the antisymmetric/symmetric components is that the symmetric components can have repeating indices while the antisymmetric components can't. Let's construct the following map from $\text{indep}(S)\rightarrow\text{indep}(A')$: if $S_{i_1\dots i_k}$ has no repeating indices then map it directly to $A'_{i_1\dots i_k}$. If $S$ does have repeating indices we record the places of repeating indices. Then delete all repeating indices, leaving us with a couple indices to be filled. Fill these empty indices with the locations but add  $n$ to each of them. 

For example let's take a look at $S_{1,1,1,5,9}$ where $k=5,n=9$. In $S_{1,1,1,5,9}$ we have repeating indices at location 1 and 2. If we delete all repeating indices we get $A'_{1,5,9,\cdot,\cdot}$ with two spots left. We fill these spots with $9+1=10$ and $9+2=11$ to 'remember' where we deleted indices. This gives $A'_{1,5,9,10,11}$. Another example: $S_{5,5,7,7,7}\rightarrow A'_{5,7,10,12,13}$. This new tensor has dimension $n+k-1$ since $k-1$ is the largest position at which a double index can occur $n+k-1$ is the largest index that will occur. It also stricly increasing indices so it can be mapped to an antisymmetric tensor and correspondingly it has $\pmatrix{n+k-1\\k}$ components. For any antiysymmetric tensor we can reverse this map so it is a bijection. So we can conclude that our original symmetric tensor has the same number of components as this new tensor. So $\#(S)=\pmatrix{n+k-1\\k}$